# Storing data into a 2-dimensional array from an infile

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, methods, file-io

I have a fairly simple issue that's been driving me crazy. Below is a method which is supposed to read an infile and store the data into a 2d array.

I keep getting compiler errors for the "inFile.next();" lines. Is there a special syntax to use with storing inFiles into arrays? Or is it something else?

Below is my method:

```
// reads and stores data in the array
public static void getData(double t[][],int m) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
         t[i][0] = inFile.next();
         t[i][1] = inFile.next();
    } // end for
} // end function getData
```

Comment: Was your compiler error "cannot find symbol"?  Telling us your actual error is always helpful when asking a question.  I'm sure, as mentioned below, that you should be using the variable keyboard instead.

Comment: Simple data. 12 rows, 2 columns of double numbers.

Comment: It was "cannot find symbol". Sorry I should have been more specific. I've only used inFile when reading data from files before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `inFile.next()` with `keyboard.nextDouble()`

Comment: Thanks that helped it to compile. So the keyboard operator is used to read infiles to arrays?

Comment: @barnaby Please stop copying and pasting code without actually understanding what it does. `inFile.next()` means "call the `.next()` method of an object named `inFile`". This only works when there is an object named inFile hanging around. `Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)` creates an object of type `Scanner`, named `keyboard`. There is still no object named `inFile`.

Comment: @Karl, Thanks for the explanation... I should not have directly given the solution...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that inFile is an instance of java.util.Scanner, you probably want inFile.nextDouble() here. inFile.next() returns a String.